# ClearQuest Custom Email

Tags: email, clearquest

I'm trying to create a custom email for ClearQuest in order to:

- format the message more neatly
- include a hyperlink to a change request (which is based on the *Defect* schema)  on our local intranet

The only way I know of to send an email is to add an email rule using a static form submission via a *Email_Rule* Stateless Record Type (which comes with the *Defect* schema). The only customization it allows is to select the fields to include in the email, the criteria specifying when to send the email (e.g. when the state changes), and who to send it to.

I'm assuming a script is run (either in VB or Perl) in order to aggregate the information needed for the email and perhaps another to actually send the email. I'm looking for one or both of those scripts. Does anyone know where those scripts are located on a ClearQuest server?

I've come across various references from IBM that pertain to custom emails, but none were very helpful.

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/4329.html (from 2003 and ClearQuest v1.1)
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/3931.html (from 2002, no version specified)

We're using **ClearQuest v7.1.2**. Does anyone know of any good references dealing with ClearQuest custom emails?

Comment: One thing I do not what to do is add a new field to the schema, for example called _URL_, and make a hook to modify the _URL_ field's value by concatenating a static URL and the _id_ field value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using Clear Quest Email Notification Package, that allows much more flexible email notifications.
[Link](http://cqadmin.org/wiki/ClearQuest_Email_Notification_Package)

Comment: I installed it and am trying to apply the package to the schema, but it doesn't show a package revision to apply. The Package Wizard requires "_You must select a package revision to apply_". The package **EmailNotification** shows up in the list, but no revision. Perhaps it isn't compatible with version 7.1.2?

Comment: Try posting on this forum: http://forum.cqadmin.org/. Pavel Dubovitsky, author of the package is very keen to help with any issues.

Answer (score 0):

The package is compatible with ClearQuest 7.1.2.
You can download new version from the following location:
http://cqadmin.org/wiki/ClearQuest_Email_Notification_Package

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of ClearQuest have a new Email notification package that does what you want and is also robust to network failures and supports different email services and a high level of security. That is, the email is saved as a record and a service runs that ensures emails get sent.

The name of the package is EmailPlus and it also uses a WebApp, EmailRelay, which performs the email notification duties.

More details found here.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH5A_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearquest.schema.ec.doc/topics/sch_pkgs/c_emp_package.htm